# Getting Dynamically Generated HTML With Nokogiri/Open URI

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, open-uri

I'm trying to scrape a site by looking at its HTML in Chrome and grabbing the data using Nokogiri. The problem is that some of the tags are dynamically generated, and they don't appear with an open(url) request when using open-uri. Is there a way to "force" a site to dynamically generate its content for a tool like open uri to read?

Comment: Take a look at [mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/). I think it might do what you want.

Comment: Depending on *how* this site generates its content, you might need to execute its JavaScript first.

Comment: Sometimes mechanize chocked in complex websites. If JRuby is an option, and mechanize doesn’t work, I will also have a look at [Celerity](http://celerity.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: Please provide an example URL.

Comment: You can't force a site to do anything it's not designed to do. You might *spoof* it into doing something different than it might normally by fiddling with the user agent, but generally, when dealing with JavaScript content, you need to use something like [Watir](http://watir.com) which can execute the JavaScript under Ruby's control.

Answer (score 4):

If reading it via open-uri doesn't produce the content you need, then chances are good that the client is generating content with Javascript.

This may be good news - by inspecting the AJAX requests that the page makes, you might find a JSON feed of the content you're looking for, which you can then request and parse directly. This would get you your data without having to dig through the HTML - handy!

If that doesn't work for some reason, though, you're going to need to open the page with some kind of browser, let it execute its clientside Javascript, then dump the resulting DOM to HTML. Something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) is an excellent choice for this kind of work.

Comment: tip #1 saved me a ton of time.